# Subset df based on partially matched columns

Tags: r, match

I would like to subset my df based on the partial match between 2 columns. An example of my df:

        `A    B value
1 ABCDEFG CDEF    25
2 HIJKLMN CDEF    36
3  OPQRST CDEF    21
4 ABCDEFG KLMN    25
5 HIJKLMN KLMN    69
6  OPQRST KLMN    98
7 ABCDEFG  PQR    85
8 HIJKLMN  PQR    74
9  OPQRST  PQR    58`

`structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L,3L), .Label = c("ABCDEFG", "HIJKLMN", "OPQRST"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CDEF", "KLMN", "PQR"), class = "factor"), value = c(25L, 36L, 21L,25L, 69L, 98L, 85L, 74L, 58L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))`

I would like to subset rows where the column B partially match with the column A. For this example the expected output would be:

`A    B value
1 ABCDEFG CDEF    25
2  OPQRST  PQR    58
3 HIJKLMN KLMN    69`

Comment: @akrun, I have tried but it's not working. `pmatch(data$B, data$A)`. Just got nomatches

Comment: Based on the example, the solution I posted below should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   filter(str_detect(A, as.character(B)))
#        A    B value
#1 ABCDEFG CDEF    25
#2 HIJKLMN KLMN    69
#3  OPQRST  PQR    58
```